# He subido una APP a la play google y no funciona en algunos moviles

Tags: java, android, app, google-play

Hola he subido mi app hecha en Java a la play store de google, es mi primera APP para subir.
Y en el emulador funciona correctamente, y en dos dispositivos que tengo sin problemas uno con Android 9 y Otro con Android 10. Pero por lo que me dicen en algunos dispositivos no funciona, se instala correctamente y va abrir y se cierra.

La SDK que he usado es la 30 y como minimo la 24??? Uno de los moviles en los que no funciona es un Android 11.

Alguno sabe decirme que puede ser???

```
DefaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jrblanco.calculadoradejoyeros2021"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
```

[Enlace a la app en google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrblanco.calculadoradejoyeros2021)

Comment: Las causas por la que se cierra son diversas, Debes revisar en https://play.google.com/console/ selecciona tu app ve a  Android Vitals > Crashes y ANRs ahí podrás ver el problema

Comment: Debes entrar en [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console) y revisar las trazas de error, que encontrarás en el apartado: **`Calidad > Android Vitals > Fallos y errores ANR`**. Por lo general te da una traza completa de los errores con información precisa sobre lo que estaría fallando.

Comment: gracias  por responder a los dos, pero he entrado en Detalles de Android vitals y esto todo vacio... sin ningun error...

Comment: Puedes depurar en un dispositivo con Android 11 tu aplicación y revisar el LogCat para obtener más información?

Answer (score 0):

Revisa este enlace tal vez necesites configurar algo adicional para Android 11 https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/migration?hl=es-419